# Vagrant & Docker: The container started never left the "stopped" state

Tags: vagrant, docker

I'm following the [vagrant guide to using docker](https://www.vagrantup.com/blog/feature-preview-vagrant-1-6-docker-dev-environments.html) but I receive this error when launching vagrant:

```
Jons-MacBook-Pro:vagrant jonhaven$ vagrant up --provider=docker
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'docker' provider...
==> default: Docker host is required. One will be created if necessary...
    default: Docker host VM is already ready.
==> default: Vagrant has noticed that the synced folder definitions have changed.
==> default: With Docker, these synced folder changes won't take effect until you
==> default: destroy the container and recreate it.
==> default: Starting container...
==> default: Waiting for container to enter "running" state...
The container started either never left the "stopped" state or
very quickly reverted to the "stopped" state. This is usually
because the container didn't execute a command that kept it running,
and usually indicates a misconfiguration.

If you meant for this container to not remain running, please
set the Docker provider configuration "remains_running" to "false":

  config.vm.provider "docker" do |d|
    d.remains_running = false
  end
```

And this is my Dockerfile (same as in the video):

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.provider "docker" do |d|
    d.image = "paintedfox/postgresql"
  end
end
```

Has anyone seen this before? I'm on OSX 10.9.4 and using Vagrant works otherwise, just not with Docker.

Edit:

I followed the advice given and verified that I could run my docker image via docker. My working docker command is this:

docker run -p 8888:8888 -d haven/play /opt/activator/activator ui -Dhttp.address=0.0.0.0

However, I can't get this to launch via vagrant no matter what combination of create_args or cmd options I use in Vagrant. To be clear, the issue is not the ports but that the docker container will not stay running.

Comment: The working docker command you have has the command "/opt/activator/activator ui -Dhttp.address=0.0.0.0".

So it seems you should have in your Vagrantfile:
d.cmd = "/opt/activator/activator ui -Dhttp.address=0.0.0.0"

Answer (score 2):

The Docker will stop if there isn't something keeping standard out going.

It looks like the paintedfox/postgresql CMD is ["/sbin/my_init"]
I assume this is a non-daemonized command that is meant to keep the container running which would mean it's exiting by error. I would try to debug by running the docker manually:

```
docker run -i -t paintedfox/postgresql /bin/bash
```

and then try to run the command:

```
/sbin/my_init
```

and see if it exits with an error. If you are running the docker in a vagrant you will first have to SSH into the Vagrant with

```
vagrant ssh
```